# Gradle build fails with mal-formed maven.org POM

Tags: maven, gradle

One of my project's dependencies apparently uses `org.gnu.gettext:libintl:0.18.2`, yet when I build (with Gradle) the process fails:

```
Could not resolve org.gnu.gettext:libintl:0.18.2.
 > Could not resolve org.gnu.gettext:libintl:0.18.2.
   > Could not parse POM https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/gnu/gettext/libintl/0.18.2/libintl-0.18.2.pom
     > The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
```

From what I see, that document *actually is* malformed and this isn't something I'm doing wrong. Is there anything I can to do bypass the error? This is completely blocking my work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the POM file is actually malformed. How such a thing was even possible defeats me. The problem is that it contains two times `</project>` at the end of the file. You won't be able to tell Maven or Gradle to just ignore this. For all they know, the POM could be really messed up.

A possible solution (apart from letting the developers know or changing version) is to download the POM file from [the URL](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/gnu/gettext/libintl/0.18.2/libintl-0.18.2.pom) Maven is looking for it and correct it by hand. In this case, it seems you just need to remove the extra `</project>`.

Then, you need to download all the other artifacts and install them in your m2 repo with the `maven-install-plugin`. In this case, I recommend you download:

- [`libintl-0.18.2-javadoc.jar`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/gnu/gettext/libintl/0.18.2/libintl-0.18.2-javadoc.jar)
- [`libintl-0.18.2-sources.jar`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/gnu/gettext/libintl/0.18.2/libintl-0.18.2-sources.jar)
- [`libintl-0.18.2.jar`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/gnu/gettext/libintl/0.18.2/libintl-0.18.2.jar)
- `libintl-0.18.2.pom` corrected by hand

And [install all of that](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/installing-secondary-artifacts.html) with

```
mvn maven-install-plugin:install-file -Dfile=libintl-0.18.2.jar -DgroupId=org.gnu.gettext -DartifactId=libintl -Dversion=0.18.2 -Djavadoc=libintl-0.18.2-javadoc.jar -Dsources=libintl-0.18.2-sources.jar -DpomFile=libintl-0.18.2.pom
```

Having done that, Maven won't try to download it again so it should work fine.